# Jest testing a looped 'await' in Redux middleware

Tags: unit-testing, redux, middleware, jestjs

I need to test (Jest) a Redux middleware that retrieves and dispatches a series of previously saved actions. It uses the 'await' operator so that the actions are completed in sequence.

This works in operation, but in testing only the first action in the sequence is popped from the saved array and dispatched.

I have tried a number of variations of the patterns found in the Redux docs, including using redux-mock-store, with no joy. I'm new to Jest (and React/Redux unit testing in general) and this is also my first crack at middleware. I feel like its the structure of the loop that is preventing the test from iterating but I can't wrap my head around how to go about it.

The guts of the middleware looks like this:

```
 //there are 3 saved actions in the test
 const actions = getState().actions
 while (actions.length > 0) {
     const action = actions.pop()
     await Promise.resolve(next(action))
           .then(()=>{
              console.log('this hits 3 times')
           })
 }
```

My initial naive try at a test was like this :

```
it(`dispatches all saved actions on request`, () => {
    _values['state'].rewind = {
        actions: {
            abcdef: [
            { type: 'TEST', payload: { value: 'rewind value 1' }},
            { type: 'TEST', payload: { value: 'rewind value 2' }},
            { type: 'TEST', payload: { value: 'rewind value 3' }}]
    }
}
const action = createTriggerAction('abcdef')
const { next, store, invoke } = create()   // spy/mocks as in Redux Docs
invoke(action)
expect(next).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);     // fails, called only once
```

})

I muddled around with making 'Invoke' an async function and 'await'ing the mocked 'next' etc. but no help.

Any pointers as to how to best do this would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: This isn't help with your test, but I'm wondering why you are using promises at all in your middleware? `Promise.resolve` returns a resolved promise, so you might as well just call `next(action)` synchronously.  Another note (from someone who has created lots of middleware), if your intention is to dispatch new actions, then you should use `storeApi.dispatch` (the storeApi is the first part of the middleware pipeline) instead of `next` as the action can then benefit from any other middleware being used, not just the ones that come after your middleware in the chain.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I couldn't find docs for 'storeApi' are you aware of any? I see your point with the middleware as written here, admittedly a naive version for purpose of the question. That said, if I want the action dispatches to be 'then-able' and each to complete synchronously (the actions could themselves be any allowable Redux action object/function/promise) how would you do it? I'd be grateful for any ideas from a more experienced hand :-)

Comment: hmm... I thought it was better documented, but the best I could find was [this paragraph in the `applyMiddleware` docs](https://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html#arguments).  Bascially, the middleware is only given `getState` and `dispatch` from the store, so it's not the complete, original store.

Comment: I think you are going to have issues if you're planning on store whatever was dispatched in the state as [the state should be serializable](https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state), so functions, promises, etc. should not be kept there.  You may be better of keeping the actions in the middleware instead. Another potential issue with trying to keep them in sequence is this will get very hard if something like redux-saga is used, as there is no promise to tell you when it is done. Happy to help if you want.

Comment: Thanks for that - I had read the blurb on non-serialized objects in state & was made peace with the trade-offs, but I might indeed play with keeping them in the middleware itself. Thanks for the suggestion :-)